# Questions about Windows kernel programming

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, question-quality

I asked a question about Windows kernel programming. But it was flagged as not being a programming question. Then I checked some other posts and found several that referenced kernel programming. I then tried to add more detail, as requested, but it was flagged as a duplicate. I think I'm simply doing something wrong. How can I communicate with an administrator?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question(s) you're talking about?

Comment: This is the post in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049063/file-system-driver-basics

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That link doesn't work.  Did you mean [File System Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982233/file-system-driver)?

Comment: @SteveP. The post I linked to is only visible to 10K users.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker So, is my answer unrelated to this question.

Comment: @SteveP. The deleted question that George linked was a word-for-word repost of the one you found.

Comment: @Gilles Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The [initial version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17982233/revisions) was very unclear because it lacked any clue that you were doing Windows kernel programming. You should have included relevant tags, at least [windows-kernel](/questions/tagged/windows-kernel) and a tag for the Windows version you're targeting, and you should also have mentioned that fact in your question (as you did in your later edits). A tag for the programming language you're using is also a good idea.

When you edited your question on Aug 1, it entered a review queue where users with sufficient privilege could evaluate whether to reopen it. The second version was still unclear; for example which OS you're targeting is buried in the middle of the first paragraph. The [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2635136) elected not to reopen your question, and I agree with them: the question hadn't improved enough.

Another problem with your question is that it is phrased poorly. Rather than ask where to find the documentation (which makes readers think you didn't try hard to find it), concentrate on the part where you have a problem and you're trying to solve it. It seems that you're trying to understand “how the system reads the directory”, and you're looking for something “that would allow the system to read the first/next directory entry”. What exactly are you after? Are you looking for a way to enumerate directory entries in the generic filesystem layer? Or are you asking which entry points your driver must implement for directory enumeration? Or something else?

I don't know what an “FSD MajorFunction” is, but that's probably ok, I'm not familiar with Windows APIs. If it's something that Windows kernel programmers would be familiar with, you don't need to explain it.

You probably do have a good question but it's still in a poor shape right now. Please edit it again to add the requested clarifications. Your question will not enter the reopen review queue again until someone votes to reopen. After the attention this question has had on meta, this is likely to happen if you do follow on those requested clarifications.

Comment: +1 very detailed, well thought out response.

Comment: I'm a Windows programmer, and I wasn't sure what FSD meant initially. Certainly not without absorbing lot of additional context. That's a good reason to avoid acronyms, at least the first time you introduce them. Make sure that your terms are clearly defined. How much harder would it be to type out "File System Driver"?

Comment: In my original post I did use the words "File System Driver" then later abbreviated it as "FSD". I did fail to say "Windows". And I failed to say "kernel mode" but I thought all programmers knew that File System Drivers run in "kernel mode".

This is my original post:

---- snip ----
I am trying to find documentation on File System Drivers (not a File System Filter Driver). I have found lots but none show how the system reads the directory.

So can anyone give me some FSD MajorFunction that would allow the system to read the first/next directory entry?

Thanks in advance.
---- end snip ----

Answer (score 7):

[File System Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982233/file-system-driver) is the only question from your profile that (I can see) was closed.  The reason was **not** that it was a *duplicate* or not *program related*, but:

[image]
I assume that since you did not provide any code or enough information that the question was put on hold.  You explain what you want, but at a very *high-level*.  I'm not familiar with what you're asking about, so I can't comment too much, but perhaps what you asked for is too general.  For a more detailed response, see [Gilles' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192543/224519).

**EDIT: (for reference to those who have < 10K rep)**
As it turns out, the question that the OP is concerned with is an exact-duplicate of the post referenced in this response, which explains the other post being closed as a duplicate.  Nonetheless, I believe my reasoning here is why the *original* question was closed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to reword it. I'll add more document references. I'll change the tag. I have very good intentions and I think the answer may be very useful to anyone wanting to write a File System Driver. But I can't edit the question because it was deleted and I can't ask a question because my account was disabled. Please, someone try to help me get out of this dilemma.